# grpcui (windows): too many colons in the address

Tags: grpc

I am trying to connect to a grpc service in the local computer from grpcui. I am using this command:

```
grpcui http://localhost:5110
```

But I am getting  the error that there are too many colons in the address.

I have tried too localhost:5110, http://192.168.1.2:5110 (the ip of the compter), and http://127.0.0.1:5110, but I always get the same error.

How could I set the address to can connect?

Thanks.

Comment: it should be without the protocol (no `http://`) have you tried `"localhost:5110"`?

Comment: If I use: grpcui -plaintext localhost:5110 it works. So it seems I don't have to indicate http to tell I want to use the unsecure way. Plaintext means that. If I would use -insecure it doesn't work, becuase it means means to use https in a unsafe way.